# Image View set Image Resource in code

Tags: java, android, image, android-layout, image-processing

I have an imageView that i want to display a little icon of the country that you are currently in. I can get the country code, but problem is i can't dynamically change the imageView resource. My image files are all lowercase

```
    String lowerCountryCode = countryCode.toLowerCase();
    String resource = "R.drawable." + lowerCountryCode;
    img.setImageResource(resource);
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(lowerCountryCode, "drawable", getPackageName());
setImageResource(id);
```

abve is my code.

Now, of course this will not work because set Image Resource wants an int, so how can i do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: String resource = "R.drawable." + lowerCountryCode;
    img.setImageResource(resource) it will not work as resource id for every resource define in r file ether use setImageDrawabel

Comment: i think you have to put images in app and by checking string u can set proper imageresources to image view..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mean you know the name of files(Drawable) which you wanna use for one and other country.

```
ImageView imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(lowerCountryCode.toLowerCase(), "drawable", getPackageName());
imgView.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(id));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work well (assuming that you really have a file with name `lowerCountryCode` in your `res/drawable/` folder)

```
String lowerCountryCode = countryCode.toLowerCase();
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(lowerCountryCode, "drawable", getPackageName());
ivCard[0].setImageResource(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

i use that code....

```
ImageView[] ivCard = new ImageView[1];

@override    
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  

ivCard[0]=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```